# jquery inArray always returns false, array created from jquery.get()

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, get

I'm getting all images that are inside of a div.

```
var favImages = $('#divPlacesILove img').get();
```

I'm checking to see of the tagImage element is inside of the array.

This always returns -1, when it should not.

```
alert($.inArray($(tagImage).attr('src'), favImages));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#divPlacesILove img').get()
```

This returns you an array of DOM elements.

```
$.inArray($(tagImage).attr('src'), favImages))
```

You are looking for a string in an array of DOM elements, so it won't find anything.

Why are you using `inArray` here?  If you want to see if the jQuery object contains an element use, `.is`:

```
$('#divPlacesILove img').is(tagImage); // true
```

Or `.filter`:

```
$('#divPlacesILove img').filter(function(){
    return this === tagImage; // or $(this).prop('src') === $(tagImage).prop('src')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for `.map()`:

```
var favImages = $('#divPlacesILove img').map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

Now `favImages` will be an array of `src` attributes.

Comment: You should actually add `.get()` after the `.map()` to make sure you get a real array, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

what is there in array is DOM elements, and you are comparing against href!!

You can try this, if you insist on using same set of functions..

```
var favImages = $('#divPlacesILove img').get();
alert($.inArray($(tagImage)[0], favImages));
```

Now `favImages` is array of images, and `$(tagImage)[0]` is your taggeed image..

Comment: I think you mean `$(tagImage)[0]`.  `search` is a string, not a jQuery object.